# ios8 How to use containing app classes in today extension (widget) app

Tags: xcode, widget, ios8

I have an application and I'm going to add a widget to it to show the containing app's summary data. Is there any way to use containing app's classes and methods in today extension app?
How should I get the widget's data from my main app?

thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use '''NSUserDefaults''' with app groups

Comment: is there any other way